# How to remove time in date time?

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

How to remove a time in date time ? on column date its only display format

[image]

I store the value on repository combobox dropdown, and it store the value including the time. How do I remove the time?

[image]

I know there's so many question about this. But the solution was by converting it into a `date.tostring("dd MMM yyyy")`. Is there a solution beside convert it into string? I want the value was date time not a conversion of string.

The code I am using still giving me a time.

```
 DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]);
```

Comment: DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]).Date;

Comment: Can you show us how the `DataSource` been set?

Comment: @HariPrasad what do you mean ? well i just select query as usual and fill it in adapter and set the gridcontrol with source.. in the database it self, using format date time  (date and time)

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger well when, i drop down the repository it still give me a time like image 2

Comment: Is there not a class of just `Date`?

Comment: @Edward iam not using any class of date, iam using the native datetime

Answer (score 1):

You just forgot to specify the date at the end of the conversion

```
DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(gridView1.GetDataRow(i)["date"]).Date;
```

Comment: have tried that, base on shannon, still give me time.. is it because i declare `System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd MMM yyyy";
ci.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern = "dd MMMM yyyy";
            ci.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss ";
            ci.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "HH:mm:ss ";
            ci.DateTimeFormat.FullDateTimePattern = "dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ";
            DevExpress.Utils.FormatInfo.AlwaysUseThreadFormat = true;`

Comment: Where you use it to display the data put `date.ToShortDateString();`

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime` as the name implify, stores date and time.
You cannot remove time part from date because time is an integral part of date.

To understand this you will have to understand how the date and time are stored. Internally, the date and time is stored as a rational number (in fractions). In computer system 24 hours are considered as numeric 1, so when your value is increased by 1 that means your date is increased by 1 day. If the value is increased by 0.5 that means your date is increased by 12 hours (half day).

So, when you have value `42613.00` that means `31st August at midnight` (just when the day started) and if you have value 42613.25 that means 6 AM of 31 Aug 2016 and 42613.50 means 12 noon of 31 Aug 2016 (and `42613.39236 means 9:25:00 AM of 31 Aug 2016`)

The smallest fraction of time that need to be stored is 1 millisecond. That means the values of DateTime field should have a precision of more than `0.0000000115740740740741`. But this is an irrational value (in binary) and hence cannot be stored as such (the nearest match is `1.00000000000000000000000000110001101101011101010000111010111111...`, ... means there are more), so I can say that milliseconds are to their nearest approximation values.

.

**That said,**

if you wish to take only `Date` part, you can create your own `class` or `struct` to store date part of the `DateTime` and then override operators for date arithematic and provide implicit conversions to convert them to `DateTime` if any code that expect `DateTime` field.

Comment: never knew so complicated.